# Bootstrap grid layout inserts a blank div when resized

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I have a collection of pictures in a grid. I'm using `"col-lg-4 col-md-6"` to get it to go 3x3 pictures in large or 2x2 in medium. However a blank div gets inserted for my medium size layout.

Take a look here at what I mean.
http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18945/

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to had

```
          <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>
```

After each double

[Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/o2w0edy6/](http://jsfiddle.net/o2w0edy6/)

Here is the doc : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <a href="#galleryModal" class="gallery-box" data-toggle="modal" data-src="//splashbase.s3.amazonaws.com/unsplash/regular/photo-1430916273432-273c2db881a0%3Fq%3D75%26fm%3Djpg%26w%3D1080%26fit%3Dmax%26s%3Df047e8284d2fdc1df0fd57a5d294614d">
                <img src="//splashbase.s3.amazonaws.com/unsplash/regular/photo-1430916273432-273c2db881a0%3Fq%3D75%26fm%3Djpg%26w%3D1080%26fit%3Dmax%26s%3Df047e8284d2fdc1df0fd57a5d294614d" class="img-responsive" alt="Image 1">
                <div class="gallery-box-caption">
                    <div class="gallery-box-content">
                        <div>
                            <i class="icon-lg ion-ios-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <a href="#galleryModal" class="gallery-box" data-toggle="modal" data-src="//splashbase.s3.amazonaws.com/getrefe/regular/tumblr_nqune4OGHl1slhhf0o1_1280.jpg">
                <img src="//splashbase.s3.amazonaws.com/getrefe/regular/tumblr_nqune4OGHl1slhhf0o1_1280.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image 2">
                <div class="gallery-box-caption">
                    <div class="gallery-box-content">
                        <div>
                            <i class="icon-lg ion-ios-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
      <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <a href="#galleryModal" class="gallery-box" data-toggle="modal" data-src="//splashbase.s3.amazonaws.com/unsplash/regular/photo-1433959352364-9314c5b6eb0b%3Fq%3D75%26fm%3Djpg%26w%3D1080%26fit%3Dmax%26s%3D3b9bc6caa190332e91472b6828a120a4">
                <img src="//splashbase.s3.amazonaws.com/unsplash/regular/photo-1433959352364-9314c5b6eb0b%3Fq%3D75%26fm%3Djpg%26w%3D1080%26fit%3Dmax%26s%3D3b9bc6caa190332e91472b6828a120a4" class="img-responsive" alt="Image 3">
                <div class="gallery-box-caption">
                    <div class="gallery-box-content">
                        <div>
                            <i class="icon-lg ion-ios-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <a href="#galleryModal" class="gallery-box" data-toggle="modal" data-src="//splashbase.s3.amazonaws.com/lifeofpix/regular/Life-of-Pix-free-stock-photos-moto-drawing-illusion-nabeel-1440x960.jpg">
                <img src="//splashbase.s3.amazonaws.com/lifeofpix/regular/Life-of-Pix-free-stock-photos-moto-drawing-illusion-nabeel-1440x960.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image 4">
                <div class="gallery-box-caption">
                    <div class="gallery-box-content">
                        <div>
                            <i class="icon-lg ion-ios-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
      <div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <a href="#galleryModal" class="gallery-box" data-toggle="modal" data-src="//splashbase.s3.amazonaws.com/lifeofpix/regular/Life-of-Pix-free-stock-photos-new-york-crosswalk-nabeel-1440x960.jpg">
                <img src="//splashbase.s3.amazonaws.com/lifeofpix/regular/Life-of-Pix-free-stock-photos-new-york-crosswalk-nabeel-1440x960.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image 5">
                <div class="gallery-box-caption">
                    <div class="gallery-box-content">
                        <div>
                            <i class="icon-lg ion-ios-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
            <a href="#galleryModal" class="gallery-box" data-toggle="modal" data-src="//splashbase.s3.amazonaws.com/lifeofpix/regular/Life-of-Pix-free-stock-photos-clothes-exotic-travel-nabeel-1440x960.jpg">
                <img src="//splashbase.s3.amazonaws.com/lifeofpix/regular/Life-of-Pix-free-stock-photos-clothes-exotic-travel-nabeel-1440x960.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image 6">
                <div class="gallery-box-caption">
                    <div class="gallery-box-content">
                        <div>
                            <i class="icon-lg ion-ios-search"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the '**Responsive Column Resets**' section in the docs? I think this is the issue you've run into:

> With the four tiers of grids available you're bound to run into issues where, at certain breakpoints, your columns don't clear quite right as one is taller than the other. To fix that, use a combination of a .clearfix and our responsive utility classes.

See more here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

Comment: I gave it a try and used `<div class="clearfix col-lg-4 col-md-6">` but doesn't seem to change anything in this case.

Comment: sorry you were right, I was doing what you suggested wrong.